# How to delete or add a <link> element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to ask if there's any way to delete and add a `<link>` element in jQuery?
if I can for example get the element `<link>` by the href of it and deleted
like this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="assets/css/1.css?v=0.1" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/2.css?v=0.1" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

will become:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="assets/css/2.css?v=0.1" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And how can I add a `<link>` element?

Comment: I can't suggest more than one duplicate, but you have the example for removing a file in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add id for this link like this

```
  <link id="style1" href="assets/css/1.css?v=0.1" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then basically you can delete it using jquery with this link

```
$("#style1").remove();
```

the other ways which you can detect this element without add ID/Class name

```
$("link[href='assets/css/2.css?v=0.1']").remove();
```

or

```
$('link[rel="stylesheet"]').remove();
```

Comment: I thought that getting elements by id is just allowed for elements in `body`

Comment: `id` and `class` are document-wide identifiers so you can use it with link tag see this [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#id-and-class)